# What does the RootNamespace tag mean in a *.vcxproj file?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I see the following in many *.vcxproj files

```xml
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  <ProjectGuid>{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}</ProjectGuid>
  <RootNamespace>yadayada</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
```

What does the `<RootNamespace>yadayada</RootNamespace>` property mean? Does it affect the output artifacts in any way?

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcproject.rootnamespace?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) say:

> The root namespace for the specified project. RootNamespace is used to determine proper naming for managed resource DLLs.

So I guess it did matter for C++/CLI projects. But seeing that it isn't mentioned in the Visual Studio 2019 SDK I'm not sure if it's still in use.

Comment: C++/WinRT takes this into consideration. I assume that `CppWinRTRootNamespaceAutoMerge` is playing a role, too. And the project files for MSBuild make references to it - e.g. the linker option `/WINMDFILE` for the Windows Metadata File is set to `$(OutDir)$(RootNamespace).winmd`.

Answer (score 0):

Besides new file default namespace naming, it affects for example to resource names:

```
<PropertyGroup>
         <RootNamespace>yadayada</RootNamespace>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
        <EmbeddedResource Include="content\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

For example:
content\Foo\Bar\123.txt becomes {RootNamespace}.content.Foo.Bar.123.txt and have to load it with `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("yadayada.content.Foo.Bar.123.txt");`

The default RootNamespace is csproj name.

To see all resource names(C#):

```
string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```